# efficent way Add key and value to Map of Set in scala

Tags: scala, optimization, functional-programming

I have an scala Map like:

```
  val myMap: mutable.Map[String, mutable.Set[String]]= mutable.Map[String, mutable.Set[String]]()
```

I would like to add in the more efficient way an element key: String and another value. The addition will check if the new key String is in the Map in positive case then add the new value to the current corresponding Set. If the key is not present, then add the key and create a new Set of values with the first element: value.

Regards 
Yasset

Comment: What have you tried already? I'd definitely recommend against mutable maps in Scala. A var with an immutable map allows you to get the identity / value right when you start abstracting the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a `(key, value)` if `key` is present in the map then `value` is added to the set. if `key` is not present then `key` with empty set it added to the `map`.

```
def update(key: String, value: String, map: Map[String, Set[String]]): Unit = 
  map.get(key)
  .map(_ => map(key) += value)
  .getOrElse(map(key) = Set[String](value))
```

Comment: In this implementation when the key is new you will add a new Set but we will need to add the value to this new set.

Comment: def update(key: String, value: String, map: Map[String, Set[String]]): Unit = map.get(key).map(_ => map(key) += value).getOrElse(map(key) = Set[String]().+(value))

Comment: Great I din't have permission to change your comments. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

What you basically need is a [MultiMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap).

```
  import collection.mutable.{ HashMap, MultiMap, Set }
  val mm = new HashMap[Int, Set[String]] with MultiMap[Int, String]

  mm.addBinding(1, "a")
  mm.addBinding(2, "b")
  mm.addBinding(1, "c")

  println(mm) 
  //prints Map(2 -> Set(b), 1 -> Set(c, a))
```

Guava comes with different [types](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap) of MultiMap. Array backed, hash based, Linked List based etc. And you don't have to mixin to create multimaps. The api is quite [elaborate](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html).

With Scala Multimap you have a restriction to use `Map[A,Set[B]]`. You cannot do `new HashMap[Int, List[String]] with MultiMap[Int, String]`.